# why is the text cuts when changing the orientation

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, xcode4.2, uiinterfaceorientation

I am using the web view to display the HTML contents and using some methods for orientation but as i change the orientation form landscape to portrait for the first time the text goes out from the view.And when i scroll from portrait to another page it shows me the perfectly.May be this happens because of the width from landscape to portrait.

The code and method i use is below:

Setting the page size

```
- (void)setPageSize:(NSString *)orientation {
NSLog(@"• Set size for orientation: %@", orientation);

pageWidth = screenBounds.size.width;
pageHeight = screenBounds.size.height;
if ([orientation isEqualToString:@"landscape"]) {
    pageWidth = screenBounds.size.height;
    pageHeight = screenBounds.size.width;
}
```

}

for orientations

```
- (NSString *)getCurrentInterfaceOrientation {
if ([availableOrientation isEqualToString:@"portrait"] || [availableOrientation isEqualToString:@"landscape"])
{
    return availableOrientation;
} 
else {
    // WARNING!!! Seems like checking [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] against "UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait" is broken (return FALSE with the device in portrait orientation)
    // Safe solution: always check if the device is in landscape orientation, if FALSE then it's in portrait.
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
        return @"landscape";
    } else {
        return @"portrait";
    }
}
```

}

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Overriden to allow any orientation.
if ([availableOrientation isEqualToString:@"portrait"]) {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
} else if ([availableOrientation isEqualToString:@"landscape"]) {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
} else {
    return YES;
}
```

}

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
// Notify the index view
[indexViewController willRotate];

// Since the UIWebView doesn't handle orientationchange events correctly we have to do handle them ourselves 
// 1. Set the correct value for window.orientation property
NSString *jsOrientationGetter;
switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
        jsOrientationGetter = @"window.__defineGetter__('orientation', function() { return 0; });";
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        jsOrientationGetter = @"window.__defineGetter__('orientation', function() { return 90; });";
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        jsOrientationGetter = @"window.__defineGetter__('orientation', function() { return -90; });";
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        jsOrientationGetter = @"window.__defineGetter__('orientation', function() { return 180; });";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

// 2. Create and dispatch a orientationchange event    
NSString *jsOrientationChange = @"if (typeof bakerOrientationChangeEvent === 'undefined') {\
                                      var bakerOrientationChangeEvent = document.createEvent('Events');\
                                          bakerOrientationChangeEvent.initEvent('orientationchange', true, false);\
                                  }; window.dispatchEvent(bakerOrientationChangeEvent)";

// 3. Merge the scripts and load them on the current UIWebView
NSString *jsCommand = [jsOrientationGetter stringByAppendingString:jsOrientationChange];
[currPage stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
```

}

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
[indexViewController rotateFromOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation toOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];

[self setPageSize:[self getCurrentInterfaceOrientation]];
[self getPageHeight];    
[self resetScrollView];
```

please help me.where do i go wrong.

Comment: Have you set webview's autoresize property properly ?

Comment: yes i have already set the webview's autoresize to flexible height and width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem is not with the code  i have changed the page size for the html page and it now works corectly.